# Why not use space-hyphen-space instead of the em dash?

Tags: typography

This is something I have wondered about for a while, and although it's the sort of thing we're conditioned to accept unquestioningly, I finally have to question it. This may come across as a bit rant-ish, but I feel it's based on valid concerns.

Why are em dashes (`this—that`) used instead of space-hyphen-space (`this - that`)?

Just to get a few points out of the way first - by "em dash", I am referring precisely to [this character](https://unicodelookup.com/#%E2%80%94/1). And yes, I am familiar with the [ways in which the em dash is used](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/em-dash-en-dash-how-to-use) - I just can't bring myself to *like* it. Its similarity to the hyphen is irritating. And while the en dash is worse, depending on the typeface, it can easily cause an awkward pause of confusion.

The following sentence is what triggered me to ask this question:

> Yet the challenges facing the nation and the world—climate change,
> inequality, the erosion of democracy—require innovations beyond
> weapons of war.

<sup>[Reference](https://www.wired.com/story/silicon-valley-business-tech-geography-innovation/)</sup>

The challenges facing the world-climate... change? No! Once we've made it to *"democracy-require"*, we realize with certainty that we have parsed the punctuation incorrectly. We backtrack, re-read as an em dash, and the meaning becomes clear. But what a waste of time, and what unnecessary cognitive load! Now, some of you reading this are probably thinking: "It is obvious to me that the character in question is an em dash." And that's fine, because in the font this Stack Exchange site currently uses for the body of its questions, it's actually pretty clear, in my opinion. I would agree. However, let's try it out in a fixed-width font (Courier New) in Dark Mode:

[image]

It's now significantly less obvious.

Let's compare a few common dashes in this typeface:

[image]

<sup>*HTML codes included for clarity*</sup>

The similarity of the en dash to the hyphen-minus is particularly hellish, but even the em dash is close enough to be a readability concern. And one can't help but wonder - if the purpose of the hyphen is to draw two ideas together, while the purpose of the em dash is to push them apart as a delimiter - then why were they made to look so darn similar?!

Now, for all practical purposes in daily life, I use space-hyphen-space instead of the em dash. But what's the worst that could happen if I were to use my convention in a publication? Would I incur all sorts of critical backlash from people accusing me of breaking the English language? Would I be "cancelled"? :-) Or would readers be pleased to find themselves parsing some sentences more easily, possibly without consciously knowing why?

Somebody please explain why em dashes have become a convention, and why some more legible alternative has not replaced it as of yet. And then, how "bad" would it be to take initiative and change this convention?

Comment: Why do you think that space-hyphen-space would necessarily be clearer? Spaces are sometimes included on both sides of a hyphen--either intentionally or carelessly--and spaces aren't always easy to distinguish--depending on kerning, font, etc.--so the situation will still be unclear for many people.

Comment: Awkward pause of confusion??  I have never been confused by the length of a dash and I spent a large part of my life never realizing that there were dashes of different lengths.  I just saw “a dash” and carried on.  Remember that dashes are used in handwriting too.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Thanks for asking. I suppose if a space is next to a hyphen that is being used as a traditional hyphen, that would be recognizable as a likely typo. Whereas if there is a space on each side of the hyphen, it should be apparent that the hyphen is not being used to join two words - but rather as a delimiter, the way an em dash would be used. Regarding space width - possibly still unclear if the kerning is poor - but more likely than not, I believe the spaces would be noticeable and helpful.

Comment: @Jim Thanks Jim. The essence of the matter is that because the differences in dash length are subtle, we still need to rely largely on context to understand whether the purpose of the dash is to join or separate. Usually we can tell from context, but there can be times when it's not so clear at first - enough so that it may trip a person up when reading aloud. So if we are needing to rely substantially on context, I wonder why we bother with different glyphs that are almost the same, instead of sticking with a hyphen and padding it with spaces when it is meant as a delimiter.

Comment: Thanks, Menatist, for the question - a subject close to my heart. I can see no reason for a bewildering variety of dashes with and without spaces: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Types_of_dash. One size fits all, and I feel I can trust good sense when it comes to the use of spaces

Comment: This is almost totally opinion-based. 'Why not use green ink more often? I'm not keen on black.'

Comment: The history of punctuation is interesting, but isn't specific to the English language; the dash was [allegedly invented by an Italian](https://www.bbc.com/culture/article/20150902-the-mysterious-origins-of-punctuation) and originally used to end a sentence. Questions that aren't about specifically English-language linguistics are generally reckoned off-topic.

Comment: Without arguing about the rant, I see the em dash as immediately recognizable and theatrical. I like it for that very reason. You may not.

Comment: Note that in MS Word, for instance, if you type << He stopped - Jill w >> [as looking angry now.], the program will automatically swap the hyphen to an en-dash: << He stopped – Jill w >>. In most fonts, the em-dash is far longer << He stopped—Jill was looking angry now. >>.

Comment: It is sometimes hard to see why anyone comes to this site with reasonable questions about meaning, usage and understanding, knowing that any hint of opinion may suffice as an excuse for closure of their question. In this case it is reasonable to discuss the meanings that may be attributed to the usages of the punctuation, and it is both high-handed and incongruous to use the *opinion* that questions involve too much *opinion* to merit any answers. This may be an issue for meta but in any case this behaviour is excessively unhelpful and deterrent to questioners. I vote to reopen.

Comment: @Anton This case seems devoid of a "correct" answer outside of opinion. Consider StackOverflow. There are plenty of answers with opinions as to the correct way to do something, or the pros/cons for a given circumstance. Questions with nothing more than opinion-based answers are closed. The question here is that type, and is more appropriate for reddit, such as "Authors and editors on reddit, why do you use an emdash?" Modifying this to inquire about the history of dashes, or how the em-dash became popular could yield answers quoting facts, not just opinions.

Comment: @jimm101 I generally respect the opinions of the closing enthusiasts and a, clearly veer a little to the generous side because I feel it better to inclu

Comment: @jimm101 I have no dislike of your viewpoint. I generally respect the opinions of the closing enthusiasts and am an unrepentant closer myself on occasion. I clearly veer a little to the generous side because I feel it better to include than to exclude, better to inform than to dismiss. Some of this controversy may owe to the closers’ wanting to create a flawless reference *product*, whereas most of the time the site is obviously acting as an excellent informative discussion *process* and I see little evidence of use of the product.

Comment: I've migrated this question because it is really about typesetting, not about English. See also [1](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/131079),
[2](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/69478),
[3](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/13697),
[4](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/68674),
[5](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/143547),
[6](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/135038),
[7](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/69434),
[8](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/96739),
[9](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/16139).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/em-dash-en-dash-how-to-use)
>
> Spacing around an em dash varies. Most newspapers insert a space before and after the dash, and many popular magazines do the same, but most books and journals omit spacing, closing whatever comes before and after the em dash right up next to it. This website prefers the latter, its style requiring the closely held em dash in running text.

Merriam Webster is relaxed about a space round the em dash, although preferring no space. I take the opposite view. To have no space creates the impression that the *words* either side are linked, whereas the function of the dash is actually to associate or contrast the *notions* on either side. It is not reasonable to expect the average reader to be familiar with all the niceties of convention that distinguish the spaced hyphen, the spaced em dash, the unspaced hyphen (which creates a hyphenated word) and the unspaced em dash (which does *not*). Coming after meaning and grammar, these are less important matters of style.

For easy readability, the presence of two em dashes in a sentence creates a parenthetically defined thought that may — or may not — be removed without destroying the main vein of thought in the sentence.

Alternatively, one em dash followed by text ending in a stop of some sort introduces a thought that complements the previous — but is still removable without destroying the line of thought.

What to do? When editing, I assume my readers to be more concerned with the subject matter and grammar than with these conventions, so I reserve the unspaced hyphen for the hyphenated words, and the spaced em dash for the parenthetic thoughts.